# Pythagorean triplet in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been asked to obtain the first 15 triplets according to [this series](https://oeis.org/A046083/internal) and this code ought to work. However, it does only produce a table (15*3) filled with zero rather than the 15 Pythagorean triplets? Any help will be welcome.

```
A = zeros(15, 3);
ii = 1;
for c = 5:120
    c2=c^2;
    for a=1:c-1
        a2=a^2;
        for b=a:c-1
            if c2-(a2+b^2) == 0
               A(ii,1) = a;
               A(ii,2) = b;
               A(ii,3) = c;
               ii=ii+1;
               if A(15, 1) ~= 0
                   flag = 1;
                   break
               end
            end
        end
         if flag == 1
             break
         end
    end
    if flag == 1
        break
    end
end
T1 = array2table(A); 
disp(T1)
```

So, the code generated a correct table on application-restart before failing on all subsequent attempts. And, now I notice that the code runs successfully **only** for the first time after every relaunch of the application. (Resolved, thanks Dan Pollard.)

Also, interested in knowing if there is any way to not write an upper limit (120) into the code.

Comment: I don't remember how well matlab treats whole numbers. If you still have problems, try to add a tolerance to your `if` check: `if abs(c2-(a2+b^2)) < 1.e-6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your if statement is ever satisfied. For example, for `c=5`, you'd expect `a=3, b=4` to be a triplet. But you're only letting `a` and `b` go up to `floor(sqrt(c-1))`, which is `2`.

Do you mean to let `a` and `b` go up to `floor(sqrt(c2-1))`?

**Edit** As the question has changed.

When you run the code, Matlab creates all the variables which you assign, and stores them in the workspace. This can be useful, but here it's hurting you as you have the variable `flag` which is stored as 1. This means that when the code runs, it checks if `flag==1` after the first run through `b`, which it is, so the code ends. Resolve this by placing `clear;` at the beginning of your script.

There isn't a practical way to remove the upper limit on `c`. Matlab has the built-in variable `Inf` but at best Matlab won't let you use it in that context. Realistically you could just replace the `120` with a really large number, but this will take more time and more memory as the number gets bigger. Computers have a finite RAM to store matlab arrays in though, and there are infinitely many pythagorean triples, so doing the calculation without an upper limit will fail in some way.

Comment: Err - typo. Same output, even if I run with `(c-1)`

Comment: Your edited code works perfectly on my machine, displaying 15 Pythagorean triples. Is it giving an error message to you?

Comment: Nothing whatsoever (R2018A / Win10). Outputting a 15*3 table filled with zeroes.

Comment: Ah I've figured it out. When you're running the code, it's storing all the same variables as from the previous time you ran it. You must have run it once and it worked, and then reused some variables each time you ran it since. The problem is `flag`. Either declare `flag=0` at the beginning, or clear all variables (simply using `clear`) at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Not a problem. I've edited my answer and attempted to answer your second question. If I've answered it satisfactorily then please accept it so that others know what helped you.